# Get contact photo by URI

Tags: android

I have android function which returns `URI` like this one:
`content://com.android.contacts/contacts/@some number@`

How can I get photo of this contact when I know `URI`?

**EDIT:**
Why following code is not working:

```
  Uri test = Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/contacts/227");
  row.setImageViewUri(android.R.id.icon, test);
```